# Does changing the name of a KeePass key file corrupt it?

Tags: keepass

I've changed name of the KeePass key file from `foobar` to `foobar.key` with the `mv` command. Next thing I see is that I cannot open my database. The error message says that I should check if database is corrupt or if I've chosen the wrong key.

Update: It just occurred to me that I created new keys (with the same name) because of the warning about "legacy keys" not being compatible in near future with KeePassXC. But I don't recall having any problems between the time of creation of the new key and renaming it.

Comment: You had a backup of that file, didn't you?

Comment: Of course not...

Comment: With your update, my first guess is that you are using the wrong key file and you are confused as to which is the correct file now that they all have the same name. If you have been using the same key for a while and suddenly it stopped working, then this has nothing to do with renaming it, This is looking like a Keepass support question.

Comment: No, but thank you. I'm pretty sure because of the system I established.

Comment: `But I don't recall having any problems these few days, between creation of the new key and renaming it.` did you close the application in between? What OS are you using? And which Keepass program are you using? It's possible that the keepass client program that you're using is caching key files in memory, so it's not rereading the updated key file, or it does not reopen the keyfile after you rename it, so it's still reading from the old inode.

Comment: I did close it. I should add it is now not limited to one database. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Apple's OSes are particularly prone to those kind of issues, as it's idiomatic in macOS (i.e. recommended by Apple's Human Interface Guideline) for an application to [follow renames](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/6396/1908). This is enforced as the default behavior in Apple's application libraries (Cocoa/Carbon). Personally, I find that this behavior always causes confusions and is generally just poor UX choice, but that's "The Apple's Way".

Comment: Apple's OS are also particularly unique because if the application uses Cocoa's/Carbon's Bookmark mechanism, then it can even follow renames even if you rename the file while the program is not running.

Comment: @IgorVuckovic can you actually reproduce the issue with a new DB? Because I can’t (keepassxc 2.2.4 on Linux). 1) created db with keyhole, 2) closed db and app 3) renamed file, 4) open db using renamed file, all fine

Comment: I did and everything was fine this time.

Comment: Then I think you either somehow have the wrong key or the wrong database, or the database is damaged. You can't modify a file's contents by just renaming it.

Comment: I assume you specified the new key file name when you re-opened your database? I don't know about KeePassXC but KeePass remembers the last-used key file name for a given database. If KeePassXC does the same thing it would obviously cause problems if you renamed the file and it is still trying to use the old name.

Comment: If you think about pathname beneath master password, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of the file does not affect file contents.  If this was the case, it would corrupt files to rename anything!  You can verify this behavior yourself:

```
% dd if=/dev/urandom of=foobar bs=4k count=1 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 0.000462499 s, 8.9 MB/s
% sha1sum foobar
d2b34df511b3d328ef23ad8f588cce50bd8b81fa  foobar
% mv foobar foobar.key
% sha1sum foobar.key
d2b34df511b3d328ef23ad8f588cce50bd8b81fa  foobar.key
```

Comment: This is true of the contents of files, but OP is asking about Keepass' specific handling of keyfiles. I do not know if Keepass also takes into account the name of the file when using it as a keyfile.

Comment: Thank you @forest. I did checked sha1sums and verified David's statement. Indeed, I'm interested in Keepass' way of handling things and, ultimately, opening my database.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not corrupt the contents of the file. But it's possible that Keepass might be running an elementary extension check. You can try renaming the file back to `foobar` and check if it works or not.

Comment: Did that, no luck.

Comment: If that does not work, then something else must have screwed up your database.

Answer (score 0):

For others as foolish as myself, here’s another troubleshooting step. I reset the key in KeepassXC because mine was going to be legacy, however in doing so, I only checked the box that said key reset, I assumed that the password would remain unchanged, however, this only made it so that I didn’t have a password, so it took me a couple days to figure out that it was as simple as using the new keyfile and just leaving the password field blank and then I could access my database again. Hopefully that helps out anyone who is in my same situation.